# How can I dock a text area inside a div

Tags: html

I have a textarea inside a div.

What property should I set so that the textarea is docked to all sides of the div? In other words, how can the text area fill the space inside the div?

I started writing JavaScript but there must be a simpler option.

Comment: As you can see by the answers below, the thing is that *it depends* :) What context is this in? In general I think width/height: 100% works, but as pointed out below, not always. If you want to be absolutely sure that it works in your context, show us some more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the css Style of the textarea to

```
height:100%;
width:100%
```

Comment: Would fail if the div's height is set to `auto`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
div textarea { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0; }
div { position: relative; }
```

But as a general rule of thumb, if an element is the only element inside of a div, it's often not needed!

**[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/Ryy9y/)**. The width and height are set for comfort reasons, but they are not necessary.

Comment: This isn't working properly for me at all. http://jsfiddle.net/BvKVY/1/ Firefox 9.0.1

Comment: I haven't tried in Firefox, but what are you seeing there? [I'm seeing it properly](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTDLs.png).

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/IZSr2.png Works in Webkit for me, fails in IE9 as well as Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it with css:

```
div { width:400px; height:160px; border:#f00 3px solid; padding: 10px; }
textarea { width:100%; height:100%; }
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/kf2dt/

Answer (score 1):

using CSS you may set the margin and padding to the div Set to 0, then for the css of of the

textarea set the height and width too 100%;

> ```
> div { margin:0;padding:0px; }
> textarea {height:100%;width:100%;}
> ```

and add overflow:hidden; to the the textarea css too hide the scrollbars if needed.

Comment: Again, would fail if the div's **parent**'s height is set to `auto`.

Comment: Exactly why this wasn't an example of using auto height. :)